# jQuery .get - how to display the result of the .get request?

Tags: jquery

I'm TRYING to get `jQuery .get` to work.

I have two files.

**I.**
Where I'm perfoming this, on `.click` event:

```
         $.get("employee.php", 
            { FirstName: substr[0], LastName: substr[1] }, 
            function(data) {

                // HOW DO DISPLAY THE RESPONSE in #div?

            }
        );
```

`substr` coming from: `var substr = ( $(this).html() ).split('<span>')[0].split(' ');`

**II.**
Params are being successfuly past to `employee.php` and firebug display the response like this:

```
<div class="employeePopUpBox">

    GET isn't empty. John, Doe

</div>
```

PHP file:

```
<div class="employeePopUpBox">

    <?php
    if(!empty($_GET)) {
        $FistName = $_GET['FirstName'];
        $LastName = $_GET['LastName'];
        echo 'GET isn\'t empty. '.$FistName.', '.$LastName;
    } else {
        echo "GET is empty";
    }
?>
```

**The quastion is how to display the response inside `div#response`?**
Any suggestion are much appreciated.

Comment: If you run into another problem, check that you have first name misspelled in .employeepopupbox   (  'GET isn\'t empty. '.$FistName.', '.$LastName;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use normal `.html()` method.

```
 $.get("employee.php", 
    { FirstName: substr[0], LastName: substr[1] }, 
    function(data) {
       $("div#response").html(data);
    }
);
```

or use this one, one-line instead

```
 $("div#response").load("employee.php?FirstName="+substr[0]+"&LastName="+substr[1]);
```

Comment: Or, save a step and use `$('#response').post(...)` instead.

Comment: Ohhh. I did not realize that `data` is the response.

Comment: @NewUser: look at my alternate solution

Comment: I have tried `.load` before. I wasn't able get it to work. I'll check this example  anyway.