# jQuery.get() - How do I use the entire result?

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-ui

[I read this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7598105/jquery-get-how-to-display-the-result-of-the-get-request), and I'm pretty sure it's 90% of what I need, but I'm after something more than just this, and my success formulating my query in Google has been less than stellar.

**What I'd like to do**

I have a form on a site that, when submitted, needs to connect with a database, and then the user needs to be apprised of the result. I'm trying to get the result page to load in a modal jQuery dialog instead of forcing a full page reload. At present, I'm just trying to create a jQuery dialog that replaces the contents of a `<div>` with the product of a PHP file. **I know I will get the PHP file's execution result this way.** That's what I'm after, but it currently is not working.

My code currently looks like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#dialog").get('include.php', function(data) {
    $("div#dialog").html(data); 
  });
});
```

And include.php is simply:

```
<?
  echo "<h1>Loaded</h1>";
?>
```

When I load the page, the original contents of `#dialog` are still there. I have a strong suspicion that what I'm failing to grasp isn't major, but I've had bad luck finding the fix. I'm a web dev newbie. [How do I wwebsite as on the internet?](http://penny-arcade.com/resources/just-wow1.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are calling [`get`](http://api.jquery.com/get/) on a jQuery result. That'a a different method than [`$.get`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/), the one you should be using:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $.get('include.php', function(data) {
    $("div#dialog").html(data); 
  });
});
```

Comment: Damn, didn't notice this mistake. +1 for you!

Comment: See, man, I knew it was gonna be something simple. Thanks! (I clicked Accept and got "You can accept an answer in 6 minutes", so I'll be back to do that)

Comment: @Martin Thank you for your answer, even though you deleted it

Answer (score 1):

i have been using Ajax call for the same purpose. So try this :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $.ajax('include.php', 
     success : function(data) {
    $("#dialog").html(data); 
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to replace the entire contents of the #dialog DOM object with the HTML you load, then you probably want to use `.load()`:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#dialog").load('include.php', function(data) {
    // no need to set the html here as .load() already does that
  });
});
```